# M2: Issue with setup multilanguage on second domain

Tags: magento2

We have created multilanguage for multi website.

On main domain work correct, but after set second domain then impossible open website (on main domain everything is ok).

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use developer mode to see the message.
```

log:

```
[2019-03-22 14:18:04] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /home/zabezcen/domains/zabezcen.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80)"} [] [2019-03-22 14:18:21] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /home/zabezcen/domains/zabezcen.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80)"} []
```

update:
.htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Host zabezcen.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host zabezcen.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

[image]

update2:
For test I deleted from `.htaccess`

```
SetEnvIf Host zabezcen.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host zabezcen.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Now, when I enter:
mywebsite.com then redirect to main domain mywebsite.pl `?SID=tc7cmm5bc6t884j77i1gcbdu17`

But when I enter mywebsite.com/en/  Then everything works correctly

So now, how to set after open website mywebsite.com redirect to mywebsite.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've set values for `$MAGE_RUN_TYPE` and `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` in your vhost file.

It depends on your `website/store` configuration, but it could be for example:

`$MAGE_RUN_TYPE = "website"`

`$MAGE_RUN_CODE = "my_second_website_code_from_store_website_table"`

Comment: yes  I think you have right and correct way. Can you please check my topic update? I have configured it this way. What should the code look like in .hta?